Is there a way of measuring the initial SHAP value of two features that have been used to create a third, using a ratio?
In the context of machine learning on python, regression or classification whatever, I sometimes do the ratio of two features to make a third feature and drop the first two. For example:
living_surface_ratio = (
    residential_building__total_living_surface 
    / building__footprint_surface
)

So at the end of my data processing pipe I only have living_surface_ratio as a feature.
I'd like to know if there's a way of measuring the shape value of residential_building__total_living_surface and building__footprint_surface despite the fact that the features are dropped and therefore no longer available.
Maybe :
shap(living_surface_ratio) = (
    0.3 * shap(residential_building__total_living_surface) 
    + 0.7 * shap(building__footprint_surface)
)

I thought about training the model with the two features and then with just the ratio, but what bothers me is that I don't really provide an interpretability of the model with the feature ratio.
I've looked at the implementation of SHAP values but it seems complicated to modify.

(A) the ratio is easier to interpret than the original features. (B) you should drop only one of the two features.

You can just define the ratio inside the prediction function that shap explains for you (with Kernel SHAP), and get shap values for the two directly. I doubt there's a universal way to work backwards to them, but that'd be off-topic here too.

The interest is to understand if my features evolve over time, (data update) I'd like to see how the explainability of my model evolves and because of which feature I gain or lose in quality.
I've also given the ratio as an example, but I'd also like to get the same inside for encoded mean or encoded ordinal variables, ...
I'm going to implement a shap value modification to swap and mask features before pipelining
